# Alternate credentials has not been saved

Tags: azure-devops, credentials

I try to use alternative credentials.

I write the name and password, then I press "Save", Azure DevOps shows me the message that the user was saved.

I navigate to other pages, if I return to the page, alternative credentials do not appear.

I have collection administrator permissions.

Another partner with the same permissions creates the alternative credential and Azure DevOps keeps the account.

The difference between the two users is that, I have a hotmail account associated with my Visual Studio license and the partner has the organization account.

I appreciate any support.

Answer (score 0):

> Alternate credentials has not been saved

As we know, the alternate credentials are created based on each user's account. To resolve this issue, make sure your account in current Organization.

However, what i want to say is that the security level of the alternate credentials is Least secure:

[image]

MS don't recommend using alternate credentials and **Azure DevOps will no longer support Alternate Credentials authentication**.

> **Deprecation Timeline**
>
> - Beginning December 9, 2019 we will disable and hide Alternate    Credentials settings for organizations that don’t have Alternate
>     Credentials set. This change will be in effect for all these
>     organizations by December 20, 2019.
> - In the coming months we will work with our customers that are still    using the feature, to help them switch to another, more secure
>     authentication method.
> - March 2, 2020 – Start gradually disabling Alternate Credentials for    all Azure DevOps organizations.

Check the [dev blogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-will-no-longer-support-alternate-credentials-authentication/) for some more details.

Hope this helps.